# Problem parsing and writing in BigQuery a huge json file with Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm trying to create a dataflow (batch) that read a file per hour from Google Cloud Storage, parse it and write an entry in a BigQuery table. The file is a .json in witch each line there is a complex json.

I've created a simple pipeline:

```
(p 
| "Read file" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(cusom_options.file_name)
| "Parse line json" >> beam.Map(parse)
| "Write in BigQuery" >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
        table=cusom_options.table))
```

Parse function is like this:

```
def parse(input_elem):
   log = json.loads(input_elem)
   result = {}

   ... # Get some fields from input and add to "result"

   return result
```

The pipeline work fine with file size of 100 Mb and 70K lines (5 min aprox per job). But when the file increase, the dataflow take more time (15 min, 200-300 Mb) or not finish and end with fail (more than a 1.5 Gb and 350K lines).

I've made some test, when I created a json sample in function **parse** but not use **input_elem** the dataflow works fine and create a row for each entry in 7-8 min.

I don't know where is the problem with the pipeline, anyone have a similar issue?

## More info

- I'm using **beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery** for auto detect schema from the BQ table, but if I use **beam.io.WriteToBigQuery** have the same issue.
- The table name is precalculated outside of the dataflow and is an input
- Parameters used in the dataflow --experiment=use_beam_bq_sink, --subnetwork=MY_SUBNET, --region=MY_REGION

Comment: How do you know that it is not finishing (vs not having waited long enough)?

Comment: The dataflow take several hours and return a fail for timeout at the end: Server unresponsive (ping error: Deadline Exceeded, {"created":"@1597627419.455096108","description":"Deadline Exceeded","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.cc","file_line":69,"grpc_status":4}). Typically one can self manage this issue, please read: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-rpc-timeout'

Comment: The documentation talks about add more resources, but the dataflow get stucked in "DestinationFileUnion" substep of WriteToBigQuery and not use any resource

Comment: Probably you need more memory for that. Since you're not using groupby or shuffle all your code will be running inside one instance with multiple containers. Try running the job with nouse_multiple_containers option.

Comment: Hi! thanks, I've search the nouse_multiple_containers option but I didn't find in documentation. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options

Comment: Could you please include in your post the parameters used to run this  job?  The error message mentioned earlier makes me think that you  need more compute power, so try to increase the --numWorkers --diskSizeGb or using  SSD-backed as is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#python_1).

Comment: Hi! I tried to increase the resources. I'm not using --num_workers (normally) and when the "Parse line json" step ended the numbers of workers increase from 1 to 600-800 aprox (worst cases), but the pipeline ended with the same error. I've tried too increase the disk_space and using SSD, limiting the max number of workers (for price) and obtained the same results. Is there anyway to know what is the resources that my pipeline demand?

Comment: For batch pipelines, Dataflow automatically chooses the number of workers based on the estimated total amount of work in each stage of your [pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#batch-autoscaling), you can try with the  methods estimate_size and fraction_consumed mentioned there. You can also try with a  [high-memory machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#n1_high-memory_machine_types) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have finally solved the problem. Parallel to the work with dataflow, some VPC networks have been created in the application, and the firewall rules were not correctly configured.

This case is similar to the one described in the documentation (**[The VPC network used for your job might be missing](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors#tsg-rpc-timeout)**). The rules existed but were not correctly configured

Thanks!